# How to cross compile SEC256k1 via mxe?

Tags: cross-compiling, autotools, bitcoin, mxe

As far as I know there aren't any packages for it in MXE so I've got to setup my own compile.

According to the docs

> If you use the Autotools, all you have to do is:
>
> ./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32.static
>
> make

And the other methods (modifying makefile) always end in this

/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `inflate'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to`deflate'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0x13d): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0x159): undefined reference to`deflateEnd'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0x1c4): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to`deflateEnd'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0x2e0): undefined reference to`deflateInit_'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0x57a): undefined reference to `deflate'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0x658): undefined reference to`zError'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0x846): undefined reference to `deflate'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0x8d8): undefined reference to`zError'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0x940): undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0xa5e): undefined reference to`inflate'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0xac8): undefined reference to `zError'
/root/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32.static/5.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/../lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:(.text+0xb53): undefined reference to`inflateInit_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:771: recipe for target 'tests.exe' failed
make: *** [tests.exe] Error 1

There isn't currently a package for SECP256k1 for mxe (and I don't expect there to be one in the near future) so I was hoping for guidance here.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your question? Did you try the solution above and it failed?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Will edit now.